# SQL - How to query for same table, same column, different data?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a short hierarchy query in SQL.

#### Tables & Columns used (Schema)

In table `table_A`, I have employee information in columns: `Name`, `ID` (HR-type data).

In table `table_B,` I have relationship data in columns `RelType`, `ChildID`, `ParentID`.

`Table_B`'s columns`ChildID` and `ParentID` are populated with `table_A`'s `ID` data.

#### Example

If my `table_A`, *ID* is `1` and my boss's *ID* is `2`, then in `table_B`, our relationship would be expressed by showing the *ChildID* as `1` and the *ParentID* as `2`.

How do I write the query to pull in the *Child* HR data and the *Parent* HR data **on the same row**?

I can pull in all the Child HR data I need with below query, but cannot figure out **how to join** or alias in a way that will pull in `table_A`'s column `ID` for two different values on the same row.

```
SELECT
  table_a.name
  table_a.id
  table_b.reltype
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id=table_b.childid
```

This obviously does not include any data for the *Parent* info. For every *ID* in `table_A`, if that ID exists in table_B, it will be in both *Child* and *Parent* `ID` columns. I want to capture all the "children" and include their "parent" (there will only be one for this purpose) on the same row.

EDIT: Below answer worked, needed two joins with aliases. Thx.

Comment: Maybe you can draw some example of desired output data (e.g. in Excel and post screenshot). If you want to roll-down the whole [Hierarchy/Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) it will become a very complicated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for two joins on `table_a`, like so:

```
select
    b.reltype
    b.childid,
    ac.name childname,
    b.parentid,
    ap.name parentname
from table_b b
inner join table_a ac on ac.id = b.childid
inner join table_a ap on ap.id = b.parentid
```